# Add and Edit AD user from ASP net core

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory

Can an ASP net core website create and edit user profile in Active directory ?
I can get information of the connected user but can I create/Edit a user in AD ?

Comment: Yes, if you interact directly over LDAP.

Comment: If you're on Windows use [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/).